# Word vba to reopen Word file without saving

Tags: vba, ms-word

Similar to "Excel vba to reopen Excel file without saving"

```
Sub ReOpen()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Workbooks.Open ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

How do I do this with MS Word?

Comment: web search "VBA how to open word file"

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub ReOpen()

    Dim Ffn As String                   ' full file name

    With ActiveDocument
        Ffn = .FullName
        .Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    End With
    Documents.Open Ffn
End Sub
```